# An unknown error occurred

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have an android app which I would like to connect to my backend.
The backend calls are made by PHP scripts while the database is built using mysql.
I uploaded the app on hostagtor.

I want to migrate that database on google cloud sql.
Things I've done so far is:

- Created a bucket on google cloud storage
- Uploaded the sql dump in the bucket.

Error:
 - When I am trying to upload it to the Google cloud sql, it throws an error!

while importing into Clousql  I wrote: gs://mybucket/abc.sql, while database name was left blank.

Comment: Hi, which UI are you using to do this?

is it the one from https://code.google.com/apis or https://cloud.google.com/console ?

Answer (score 0):

Common mistakes are:

1. Missing `use <database>` statement at the beginning of the dump file.
2. The database does not exists.
3. You did not use `--hex-blob` option while generating the dump.

Comment: Got that thing Solved. My syntax was incorrect. I wrote USE abc instead of USE 'abc' where abc is the database name.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the file I uploaded wasn't encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.