# unknown error on import

Tags: phpmyadmin, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

After looking all over Stackoverflow and Google forums, I can not seem to get the sql file to import from Google Storage. I found a lot of people saying to try ['USE XXX'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/pFGe7LsbUaw) where XXX is the name of the database but that doesn't seem to work. I saw another say to use [BOM with UTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225271/an-unknown-error-occurred) 8 but I could not find how to do that with phpMyAdmin. Any solutions/suggestions would be great.

Database is accessed via phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to produce a dump suitable for import is using mysqldump. The instruction on that are [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import-export#migrate).

Comment: I was able to run a mysqldump from exec in php and then upload the file to Google Storage. The first time it said "Reading <file>" and then "Unkown error occured". The second time I added 'USE <DB>' and it said "Importing..." and then the same error. Razvan, do you have any thoughts of what this might be? The file after upload is 109mb

Comment: Please write to cloud-sql@google.com and indicate the instance name. We currently don't expose the exact errors the mysqldump is throwing but we can look that up manually.